# Cant link to jcenter by proxy

Tags: android, android-studio

I try to download the gradle 2.2.2 but faild. （android studio 3.4.2）

I try it by proxy(lantern or ssr), actually it works with tests. But when I run this project it was failed. And I had tried the source of Ali. Unfortunately, this solution cant work for me. Has anyone met？

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.taobao.android:weexplugin-gradle-plugin:1.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
```

proxy msg:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.2/gradle-2.2.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.2/gradle-2.2.2.pom'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.2/gradle-2.2.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.2/gradle-2.2.2.pom'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.2/gradle-2.2.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.2/gradle-2.2.2.pom'.
               > org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
   > Could not resolve com.taobao.android:weexplugin-gradle-plugin:1.3.
```